# Variable not refreshing on re-run. How do I pass down the variable?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to pass down the variables I create when hitting the /pay route to the /success_api route. Namely I need to pass down 'content', 'productSelectTotal', 'productSubTotal', and 'shipping'. When I trigger /pay the first time, it sets content which is then passed down when I am redirected to '/success', however on all subsequent requests, the value of content, productSelectTotal, productSubTotal, and shipping in the 'success_api' get function remain the same.

Any ideas how to make sure they are being refreshed every time the value of the variables in the parent function is updated?

```
 router.post('/pay', (req, res, next) => {
   fs.readFile('ProductDB.json', function (error, data) {
     if (error) {
       res.status(500).end()
     } else {
       const productsJson = JSON.parse(data)
       console.log(req.body.items)

       let content = [];

       let productSelect = req.body.items.map(product => {
         const itemJson = productsJson.find(function (i) {
           return i.productName === product.productName
         }).variations.find(function (i) {
           return i.id === product.id
         })

         product.id != null ?
           content.push({

             // PUSH TO CONTENT HERE
             "name": product.productName,
             "sku": product.id,
             "price": itemJson.variationPrice / 100,
             "currency": "USD",
             "quantity": product.qty
           }) :
           false
       })

       let tariffObj = {
         "uk": 3.6,
         "us": 11.6,
         "rest-of-world": 11.6,
         "eu": 8.2
       }


       let postalCategory = req.body.postalCategory
       let postalTarrif = tariffObj[postalCategory]


       let shipping = postalTarrif;
       let productSelectPrices = content.map(item => item.price * item.quantity);
       let productSelectTotal = productSelectPrices.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, shipping).toFixed(2)
       let productSubTotal = productSelectPrices.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0).toFixed(2)



       const create_payment_json = {
         "intent": "sale",
         "payer": {
           "payment_method": "paypal"
         },
         "redirect_urls": {
           "return_url": `http://localhost:3000/success`,
           "cancel_url": `http://localhost:3000/cancel`
         },
         "transactions": [{
           "item_list": {
             "items": content
           },
           "amount": {
             "currency": "USD",
             "total": productSelectTotal,
             "details": {
               "subtotal": productSubTotal,
               "shipping": shipping
             }
           },
           "description": "first tea added to the store"
         }]
       }

       paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
         if (error) {
           throw error;
         } else {
           console.log("Create Payment Response");
           console.log(payment);
           for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
             if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
               let redirectURL = payment.links[i].href
               res.json({
                 redirectUrl: redirectURL
               })
             }
           }
         }
       });

       /*
       After creating the response the user is redirected to paypal, where they enter their payment information after which they are returned to the website where the / success_api call is made
   */
       router.route('/success_api').get((req, res) => {

         //CONTENT NOT UPDATED WITHIN THIS FUNCTION ON RE - RUNS

         console.log('re routed')
         const payerId = req.query.PayerID
         const paymentId = req.query.paymentId

         const execute_payment_json = {
           "payer_id": payerId,
           "transactions": [{
             "item_list": {
               "items": content
             },
             "amount": {
               "currency": "USD",
               "total": productSelectTotal,
               "details": {
                 "subtotal": productSubTotal,
                 "shipping": shipping
               }
             }
           }]
         }



         paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
           if (error) {
             console.log(error.response);
             res.json({
               message: 'payment error'
             })

           } else {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
             res.json({
               message: 'Payment Successful'
             })
           }
         });

       })

     }

   })
 })
```

Comment: Why is it able to get the values the first time (e.g. content), but on all subsequent requests it doesn't update?

Comment: you have defined the success_api method inside the pay method, Is it mandatory  ? I mean has it been mentioned in the docs or something. This is quite confusing!!

Comment: why dont you save those variables in db and fetch it in success_api.

Comment: I am totally agree with what the OP said.  You can save it to DB like mongo or can prefer redis for performance. You can even use localstorage or indexedDB(not recommended for sensitive data).

Comment: thanks so much for your response guys. No, I tried moving the success_api inside the pay method to see if it would pass down the variables (which it does on the first run). I actually ended up taking it out of the pay method (as it was before) and retrieving the variables from local storage like you guys suggested. I may change it mongo or redis at a later stage. Thank you so much!